# Problem with ANSI escape code: ←[1;34mFOLDERNAME←[0m

Tags: powershell, shell, adb, ansi-escape

I type in my adb shell (via PowerShell 7, Windows 10) a simple command and it shows this:

```
root@android:/system # ls
ls
CSCVersion.txt       ←[1;34mcsc←[0m           ←[1;34mlib←[0m                    tima_measurement_info
SW_Configuration.xml ←[1;36mcsc_contents←[0m  ←[1;34mlib64←[0m                  ←[1;34mtts←[0m
←[1;34mT9DB←[0m                 ←[1;34metc←[0m           ←[1;34mlost+found←[0m             ←[1;34musr←[0m               
←[1;34mapp←[0m                  ←[1;34mfake-libs←[0m     ←[1;34mmedia←[0m                  ←[1;34mvendor←[0m            
←[1;34mbin←[0m                  ←[1;34mfonts←[0m         ←[1;34mpriv-app←[0m               ←[1;34mxbin←[0m              
build.prop           ←[1;34mframework←[0m     recovery-from-boot.bak
←[1;34mcameradata←[0m           info.extra    ←[1;34mrfs←[0m
←[1;34mcontainer←[0m            kern_sec_info ←[1;34msaiv←[0m
```

It seems like a problem with [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Typing `"$([char]0x1b)[0;31mtest123"` yields this result:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: `ls --color=never` <- to make `ls` return output without the escape sequences

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen is there a way to keep colors?

Comment: @Ooker - you can keep the color IF you run the code in a console that supports the ANSI escape code stuff. check your console to see if it does or doesn't ... at the moment, i would bet that the console you used does NOT support such.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey how do you check that? The console is PowerShell 7. I think it should support ANSI escape code, right? It does have colors for commands

Comment: @Ooker - what OS? the windows console that ps7 uses by default seems to NOT support that. the "new" terminal app _does_ support it. for other console/host combos ... i don't know how to do that - other than literally adding a test and seeing if one gets errors of some sort.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey windows 10. It would be strange to not support that. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: they added the "new" terminal specifically because of the many lacking features of the basic console. so ... if you want to use ansi character format controls, you likely otta install the version that supports what you want. there is a way to get it installed for all users, but that seems to prevent auto-updates.

Comment: @Ooker PS7 on Win10 supports it definitely. Just tested it with the adb shell ```adb shell ``` following -```ls --color```(mine does not use colored output by default). PS5.1 does support it as well. The arrow "←" in your output is strange. Seems that your device does not send the correct escape sequence.

Comment: What happens when you use the following in PS (without adb): ```"$([char]0x1b)[0;31mtest123"```. Does it output red colored text?

Comment: @pwnosh [red and blue](https://i.imgur.com/oJU4LAx.png)